# Error: ng:areq Bad Argument Argument 'msgController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs, websocket, modal-dialog

I am new to angularJS and I couldn't understand why this error is coming. Please help find where I have done mistake.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
    <title>Angular JS Web-Socket</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">        
</head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/chat.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ngDialog.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ngDialog-theme-default.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ngDialog.css">

<body>
    <button ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-click="openChatBox()">Open</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**chatBox.html**

```
<script src="lib/ngDialog.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-websocket.js"></script>
<script src="js/socket.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ngDialog.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/chat.css">
<!-- The Modal -->

<div id="myModal" class="modal" ng-app="chatSocket">

  <!-- Modal content -->
 <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
  <div class="menu">
        <div class="name">Bot</div>
        <div class="close">Close</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" ng-controller="msgController">
<h2>Modal body</h2>
  <label ng-repeat="item in socket.msg">
      Name : {{item.name}} <br>
      Msg : {{item.msg}}
  </label>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
  <form ng-submit="submit()"> 
    <input type="text" ng-model="msgbox">               
    <button id="sendMsg" type="submit" >Send Message</button>
   </form>
</div>
```

**chat.js**

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngDialog']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, ngDialog) {
$scope.openChatBox = function() {
    ngDialog.openConfirm({template: 'chatBox.html',
        scope: $scope //Pass the scope object if you need to access in the template
    }).then(
        function(value) {
            //You need to implement the saveForm() method which should return a promise object
            $scope.closeChat().then(

            );
        },
        function(value) {
            //Cancel or do nothing
        }
    );
};
});
```

**socket.js**

```
angular.module('chatSocket', ['ngWebSocket'])
.factory('socket', function ($websocket) {

    // Open a WebSocket connection
    var ws = $websocket("ws://" + document.location.host + document.location.pathname);
    var msg = [];

    ws.onMessage(function (event) {
        console.log('message: ', event.data);
        var response;

        try {
            response = event.data;
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('error: ', e);
        }

        msg.push({
            name: "Bot",
            msg: response,
        });
    });

    ws.onError(function (event) {
        console.log('connection Error', event);
    });

    ws.onClose(function (event) {
        console.log('connection closed', event);
    });

    ws.onOpen(function () {
        console.log('connection open');
        ws.send('HELLO SERVER');
    });

    return {
        msg: msg,
        status: function () {
            return ws.readyState;
        },

        send: function (message) {
            console.log(message);
            msg.push({
                name: "User",
                msg: message,
            });
            ws.send(message);
        }
    };
 })

.controller('msgController', function ($scope, socket) {
$scope.socket = socket;
$scope.submit = function () {
    socket.send($scope.msgbox);
};  
});
```

If I didn't use `msgController`, the dialog box is opening. when I include this, the error is shown and couldn't open the dialog box.

Comment: You didn't reference your second module `chatSocket` as a dependency for first module `var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngDialog','chatSocket']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are referencing the `msgController` in `openConfirm` method of `ngDialog` and you didn't define it.

```
ngDialog.openConfirm({
    template: 'chatBox.html',
    controller: 'msgController',
    scope: $scope //Pass the scope object if you need to access in the template
})
```

In addition to that you have specified `msgController` in `chatSocket` module and you are using it in `MyApp` module which is why you are getting the error.

You need to specify the `chatSocket` as dependency to `MyApp` module and define the `msgController` on `MyApp` module like blow:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngDialog','chatSocket']);

app.controller('msgController', function ($scope, socket) {
$scope.socket = socket;
$scope.submit = function () {
    socket.send($scope.msgbox);
};  
});
```

Comment: If I define msgController on MyApp module, I get the following error. "Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider"  https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=MainCtrlProvider%20%3C-%20MainCtrl%20%3C-%20msgController

Comment: @Kavipriya that is because in your `msgController` you are referencing `socket` factory which is defined in chatSocket` module. So to solve the issue you can specify `as dependency to `MyApp` module. See the updated answer

Comment: Yeah I have done that also but dint help. I am getting this error  "Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error"

Comment: You should load all the scripts in index.html file, So remove the scripts from chatBox.html and place it inside index.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works :) and  i have a doubt what difference does it makes to add in index.html or in chatBox.html?

Comment: Because you're working in a single page application, all the scripts the are needed for the entire application should be loaded in index.html. If you are working with Asynchronous module definition scripts or traditional jsp/asp/php you can load in any html